# How do i make a CSS animation run infinitely

Tags: css, animation

I'm tryin to make a infinte animation but at some point it seems to hop back to the start.

Thats the code

```
h1 {
  background: url(Pepesad.png) repeat-x;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 1em auto;
  max-width: 600px;
  height: 512px;
  animation: flybirds 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes flybirds {
  from {
    background-position: 0px 0px
  }
  to {
    background-position: 300px 0px
  }
}
```

Comment: all depend on the size of the image you are using (and the image itself) so share the image

Answer (score 0):

Some of the CSS rules you mentioned for h1 seems unnecessary for your purpose. Mentioning the width gives the animation very less space. Consider providing the h1 a container/ wrapper and set appropriate width for it.

```
h1 {
    background: url(Pepesad.png) repeat-x;
    height: 512px;
    width: 5076px;
    animation: flybirds 1s linear infinite;
}
```

Also in the keyframes you have mentioned the x-axis to 300px which cause the breaking effect during the animation. I suggest you update it

```
@keyframes flybirds {
    from {
        background-position: 0px 0px
    }

    to {
        background-position: -100% 0px
    }
}
```

Another alternative you could use is :

```
 @keyframes flybirds {
    0% {
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translate3d(-1692px, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Note: the reason why I suggest to use an additional  at all, rather than animating background-position on h1, is so that we can use an animated transform to do the movement, which is much more performant.

Comment: What is the reason to set OPs `h1` to `width: 5076px` when he wants it to have max of `600px` and why in the second alternative you set translation to exactly `-1692px` ?

Comment: I simply gave some random numbers. As far as the concept is clear I don't think the numbers matter and in the question that wasn't specified so I gave some big values so that the changes are noticed easily.